# Can you add a permanent symbol before the user's input?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-prompt, readline

I've recently started using javascript but I'm a novice. My object is to add a symbol (> ) before any user input in the console (I don't want to store it, I just want the user to see it when typing in the console)

I've already tried to use a prompt with readline but when the system prints something the symbol disappears

```
    console.clear()
    radarPlugin(exp, options);
    setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(exp.username + " has joined on " + settings.host + ":" + settings.port);
    rl.prompt();
    }, 1000);
```

the output is 
"> *exp.username* has joined on *host*:*port*"

but it should be
"*exp.username* has joined on *host*:*port*"
and then the symbol 
"> " on another line.

Comment: What console are you referring to? The terminal that you're running your nodejs script in?

Comment: What do you mean by "*when the system prints something*"?

Comment: yes, with console i mean the terminal

Comment: I mean whenever I print something on the terminal